# Expanding macro within macro

Tags: c++

In the following example I expect to see

```
 doSomething 
 asserting in "doSomething()"
```

However i dont see any output on console.

When I use HUTAssert(doSomething()) in main() , I see the expected output, so I expect this has to do with expending a macro within another macro

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#define LOPTAssertEnabled 1
#define HUTAssert(expr) ( (expr)? (void(0)) : assertMe(#expr) ) 
#define HAOPAssert(expr) ((isLOPTAssertEnabled())? HUTAssert(#expr) : void(expr))
void assertMe(char const* expr) {
    std::cout <<" asserting in "<<expr; 
}
bool doSomething() {
    std::cout <<" did something "<<std::endl;
    return false;
}

bool isLOPTAssertEnabled() {
    return LOPTAssertEnabled;
}

int main() {
    HAOPAssert(doSomething());
}
```

Comment: You seem to know what `#expr` does. What are you expecting from `HUTAssert(#expr)`?

Answer (score 4):

You can easily see what preprocessor is doing. For example, with gcc (g++) you can use the "-E" option to see what preprocessor is producing. In your case, you are getting this:

```
void assertMe(char const* expr) {
    std::cout <<" asserting in "<<expr;
}

bool doSomething() {
    std::cout <<" did something "<<std::endl;
    return false;
}

bool isLOPTAssertEnabled() {
    return 1;
}

int main() {
    ((isLOPTAssertEnabled())? ( ("doSomething()")? (void(0)) : 
           assertMe("\"doSomething()\"") ) : void(doSomething()));
}
```

I believe, this is not what your are expecting. However, if you strip off `#`, which is "stringfying" your token, from `HUTAssert(#expr)`, I believe it will be close to what you are expecting